# Spring Boot Security + Spring Boot REST Repository config issue

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-repositories

I have Spring boot application as below [image]
And the Web Security Config as

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("chiru").password("{noop}chiru").roles("ADMIN").and().withUser("user")
                .password("{noop}user").roles("USER");
        // @formatter:on
    }
}
```

And the i have Repository as below

```
public interface IssuesRepository extends CrudRepository<Issues, Integer> {

}
```

when i try to add data through REST Using Postman with Basic Authentication, its failing[image]
[image]

Comment: Firstof all in the password i see that you make {noop}... is that normale ?
Else try to put on top of your rest method @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN')")  and test if it will be ok

Comment: {noop} means i dont want to encrypt the password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `httpBasic()` instead of `formLogin()`, like `http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();`.

formLogin() is used when you want to have login page to authenticate the user (so you have), but in your example you are using http basic to do that. Spring security doesn't recognizes your http basic header and returns login page.

PS. You can use both methods `http.httpBasic().and().formLogin()`